# How to convert JLabel.getIcon() to BufferedImage

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jlabel, bufferedimage

I have a JLabel that contains only an icon, and I can get the Icon with label1.getIcon(), but I can't figure out how to convert that Icon into a BufferedImage. Just FYI, I'm not talking about ImageIcon, only Icon. Also, I have seen the question at [How to convert Icon from JLabel into BufferedImage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6368160/how-to-convert-icon-from-jlabel-into-bufferedimage), but I can't seem to figure it out.

As always, any examples or explanation are much appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: `label1.getIcon()` How is `label1` created?

Comment: JLabel label1 = new JLabel();....and then it is added to an array of JLabels, but that doesn't really matter.

Comment: "but I can't seem to figure it out." what confuses you in AndrewThompson's answer in the question you have specified?

Comment: *"but that doesn't really matter."*  Yes it does, or at least it might.  Since you apparently have no idea how to do this, it would pay not to jump to conclusions about what is/is not necessary or relevant.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @NikolayKuznetsov I did exactly what AndrewThompson described, but it didn't work...I'm really not sure why.

Comment: I think you need to see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830533/how-can-i-convert-an-icon-to-an-image)

Comment: I'll try that right now...

Comment: @Learner  Its begining to work now...thanks!!!

Comment: @iphonedev7 then i think it should be my answer :) please accept it

Answer (score 3):

You may try this.

```
// Get the icon
Icon ico = label1.getIcon();
// Create a buffered image
BufferedImage bimg = new BufferedImage(ico.getIconWidth(), ico.getIconHeight(),
                                       BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
// Create the graphics context
Graphics g = bimg.createGraphics();
// Now paint the icon
ico.paintIcon(null, g, 0, 0);
g.dispose();
```

Answer (score 3):

As `JLabel.getIcon()` returns a *Icon* so you want to convert the Icon to bufferedImage.I think you need to [view this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830533/how-can-i-convert-an-icon-to-an-image).Here you can get the way through which you can convert a icon to *BufferedImage*

Comment: While I agree the link is a helpful - I might suggest that this more of a comment then an answer - IMHO