# Crop Icon in Java

Tags: java, image, swing

How to crop an Icon object in Java, for use within the Java Swing framework ?

Say you get an Icon, and you would like to use it in a `JButton`, but it is too big. How do you crop it ?

Comment: Downvoters, would you mind explaining ? I looked thoroughly on the web and stackoverflow before posting this question, didn't find anything, and it seems this could be some reusable knowledge.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(
  new FilteredImageSource(
    iconToImage(icon).getSource(), 
    new CropImageFilter(leftX, topY, width, height)
  )
);
```

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5830533/how-can-i-convert-an-icon-to-an-image) to implement the `iconToImage` method to convert your icon to an image.